# How to make a dynamically created button flash or change colour when a string is received from serial port?

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

How to make a particular button in dynamically created buttons flash and change its color when a value is received from a serial port. It should be something like this: If a character is received form the serial port, a button in array of buttons should start flashing.

Comment: it is generally good practice to show some example code, an indication that you have done some research before asking your question here. For example - had you already managed to receive data from the serial port?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this article - based on    `SerialPort.DataReceived Event`

Creating on instance :

```
   SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort("..");//Adjust value

    mySerialPort.BaudRate = ...;//Adjust value
    mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
    mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
    mySerialPort.DataBits = ..;//Adjust value
    mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;

    mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);

    mySerialPort.Open();

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.ReadKey();
    mySerialPort.Close();
```

Event :

```
 private static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender,  SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
 {
        //Change
 }
```

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived.aspx

Change Colour :

```
<input type="button" value="click me" onclick="this.style.color='#000000';
this.style.backgroundColor = '#ffffff'" />
```

You can use this code - based on `RegisterClientScriptBlock`

```
      // Get a ClientScriptManager reference from the Page class.
      ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
      StringBuilder cstext2 = new StringBuilder();
      cstext2.Append("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
      cstext2.Append("document.getElementById("button").bgcolor="#Insert Color Here";</");
      cstext2.Append("script>");
      cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(.., .., cstext2.ToString(), false);
```

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/vstudio/z9h4dk8y.aspx